# Show bootstrap alert on button click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the code , so can anyone help me why im not seeing bootstrap alert when i click the button , it wont show on the page !

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.alert').show()
}) });</script><title>Bootstrap Example</title><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

.alert{display: none;}

```
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
            <div  style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100px;">

            </div>
             <div  style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100px;">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container">
    <button>Send Message</button>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
<button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        Success! message sent successfully.
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why did you change your entire question? Don't do that, this way your previous question and all answers to it will become useless to other people...

Comment: If you need answers to other question, make a new one. So, please, edit your question to return it to the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its really hard when you dont provide your actual code, but... here goes an idea to achieve something similar to what is in the picture using classes from bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 600px;">
            content here -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 300px;">
                    content here -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 300px;">
                    content here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

try this code in an ambient where you are pointing to bootstrap files or it will be totally wrong.

Comment: God bless you .